# TypeScript VueJS: Using watcher with computed property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a custom component that will allow me to use arbitrary `<div>`s as radio buttons. Currently my code looks like so:

```html
<template>
    <div
        class="radio-div"
        :class="selected ? 'selected' : ''"
        @click="handleClick"
    >
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.radio-div {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.radio-div.selected {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
</style>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class RadioDiv extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    val!: string;

    @Prop({
        required: true
    })
    value!: string;

    selected = false;

    mounted() {
        this.selected = this.value === this.val;
    }

    @Watch("value")
    onChange() {
        this.selected = this.value === this.val;
    }

    handleClick(e: MouseEvent) {
        this.$emit("input", this.val);
    }
}
</script>
```

To utilize this I can put it in a template like so:

```html
<template>
    <div class="q-pa-md">
        <q-card>
            <q-card-section class="bg-secondary">
                <div class="text-h6">Political Affiliation</div>
            </q-card-section>
            <q-separator />
            <q-card-section>
                <radio-div v-model="politicalParty" val="Republican">
                    <div class="text-h6">Republican</div>
                    <p>Wrong answer</p>
                </radio-div>
                <radio-div v-model="politicalParty" val="Democrat">
                    <div class="text-h6">Democrat</div>
                    <p>Wrong answer</p>
                </radio-div>
                <radio-div v-model="politicalParty" val="Independent">
                    <div class="text-h6">Independent</div>
                    <p>These people clearly know what's up</p>
                </radio-div>
            </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import RadioDiv from "../components/RadioDiv.vue";

@Component({
    components: { RadioDiv }
})
export default class Profile extends Vue {
    politicalParty = "Independent";
}
</script>
```

This works as expected. I can click on the `<div>`s and it switches which one is selected and updates the variable appropriately.

But now I want to tie this into a global state manager. So instead of a local `politicalParty` variable, I have a ***computed*** property like so:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import RadioDiv from "../components/RadioDiv.vue";
import globalState from "../globalState";

@Component({
    components: { RadioDiv }
})
export default class Profile extends Vue {
    get politicalParty() {
        return globalState.politicalParty;
    }

    set politicalParty(val) {
        globalState.politicalParty = val;
    }
}
</script>
```

Putting a `console.log` statement in the setter I can see that it ***is*** getting called, and the variable is being updated. But putting a `console.log` statement in my `value` watcher (in the `RadioDiv` component) shows it's **no longer** being called now that I'm using computed properties.

What's the secret to get my `RadioDiv` reactive again, now that I'm using global state?

### Update

The issue doesn't seem to be specific to my custom components, or to watchers. I decided to ignore this and move on while waiting for an answer from StackOverflow and ran into the issue again with Quasar's components:

```html
<template>
...
            <q-card-section>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <q-slider v-model="age" :min="0" :max="100" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        {{ ageText }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </q-card-section>
...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
...
    get age() {
        return globalState.age;
    }

    set age(val) {
        globalState.age = val;
        this.ageText = "You are " + val + " years old";
    }
...
</script>
```

This led me to try using no custom components whatsoever:

```html
<template>
...
    <input type="text" v-model="test" />
    <p>Text: {{ test }}</p>
...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
let testVal = "";
...
    get test() { return testVal; }
    set test(val) { testVal = val; }
...
</script>
```

Once again: No reactivity. When I use a computed property with `v-model` nothing seems to change after the call to `set`

Answer (score 0):

If `globalState` were just an `Object`, then it would *not* be reactive, so `computed` is only going to read its value *once*. Same for `testVal`, which is just a `String` (also not reactive itself).

To make the `test` computed prop reactive to `testVal`, create `testVal` with [`Vue.observable()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable):

```js
const testVal = Vue.observable({ x: '' })

@Component
export default class Profile extends Vue {
  get test() { return testVal.x }
  set test(val) { testVal.x = val }
}
```

Similarly for `globalState`, exporting a `Vue.observable()` would allow your computed props to be reactive:

```js
// globalState.js
export default Vue.observable({
  politicalParty: ''
})
```